# Debugging a Nextjs App with Custom Server (Express)

Tags: node.js, debugging, next.js, vscode-debugger

I'm not finding any clear posts about this specific problem so I'll open a thread.

I'm trying to use the VScode debugger to debug a **Next.js** application wrapped in a custom **Express.js** server. My usual `npm run dev` script runs a prebuild task then executes `nodemon`. I don't care much for `nodemon` during debugging if it's a pain to set it up, but it'd be cool to keep it for sure.

I tried several configurations (`launch.json`). Some of them work once but then hitting the endpoint again does not trigger the breakpoints. In any case, here are some configs I tried.

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "<name>",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "dev"],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
     {
       "type": "node",
       "request": "launch",
       "name": "<name>",
       "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<path-to-main>",
       "preLaunchTask": "npm: prebuild",
       "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/<build>/**/**/*.js"],
       "outputCapture": "std"
     }
  ]
}
```

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "<name>",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      },
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a solid way to just launch the debugger and it launches the customer server and triggers on all breakpoints?

Comment: Running the last one with the `npm run dev` script set to `npm run build && node <path-to>/main.js` seems to work. It's not nodemon, but meh.